# What is the Telephone field of Service Call in SAP B1 SDK?

Tags: sapb1

What is the Telephone field of Service Call in SAP B1 SDK?
I tried to use field found in OSCL table of service call but it gives the following error message **Unable to lookup `Telephone': Unknown name.**

```
<?php
   $oService->CustomerCode = "000001";
   $oService->Subject = "Created";
   $oService->Telephone = "07883.....";
?>
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: What service are you trying to call?

Comment: It is the form called Service Call in SAP B1 service module, it has field of telephone but i do know how it called in SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `SAPbobsCOM` object in SDK, the field is Telephone

```
SAPbobsCOM.ServiceCalls rs = SboConnection.Company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oServiceCalls);

rs.Telephone = "897967969";
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using PHP now where I declare rs or oService like this $rs=$mycomp->GetBusinessObject(191);   191 is object type of Service Call. But it does not find Telephone field

Comment: $oService=$mycomp->GetBusinessObject(191);
$oService->CustomerCode = "000001";
$oService->Subject = "Created";
$oService->Telephone = "07883....";

Comment: Are you using MS Sql Server as your DB? If so, are you able to run this query?: "select T0.Telephone from OSCL T0"

Comment: Yes I'm using MS Sql Server as my DB, and I can run that query

Comment: I used the telephone of contact person from BP Master Data it works fine, thank you